# Random works differently depending on Start Debugging or "Step Into/Over"

Tags: c#, for-loop, random

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    byte wtf = (byte) new Random().Next(10);
    Console.Write(wtf + " ");
}
```

This code produces the expected output if I run the program step by step:
4 6 9 2 9 0....

But if I just hit the Start Debugging or -Without Debugging this happen: 
7 7 7 7 7 7...

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your loop is happening too fast.  The `Random` class uses the system clock for a seed, I believe, and when your loops run during the same millisecond, it gets the same seed.

Here's what you really need to do: instantiate `Random` *outside* of your loop:

```
var rand = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    byte wtf = (byte) rand.Next(10);
    Console.Write(wtf + " ");
}
```